# Associate a network security group to a subnet in different resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network, network-security-groups

I know I can use the following cli to Associate a network security group to a subnet

`az network vnet subnet update -g MyResourceGroup -n MySubnet --vnet-name MyVNet --network-security-group MyNsg`

However, this cli does not work if the subnet and the NSG are in different resource groups. In Azure portal I can do it. Is there any way I can do it with cli?

Comment: The note for the `--network-security-group` argument mentions: "Name or ID of a network security group". Maybe you could use the full resource ID of the NSG? (which includes the sub and RG) Disclaimer: did not try this.

Comment: Great thanks, it works !

Comment: @Steve , If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this in our local environment, it is working fine.

We have created a `NSG` & a `Subnet` in two different resource groups in Same region.

As per the `az network vnet subnet update` [cmdlet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-vnet-subnet-update) , We can pass the Name or Resource Id of NSG to   `--network-security-group` flag . Using that we  are able to attach the NSG to that subnet across different resource groups.

**Here is the sample output for reference :**

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! It works!